# What is “sexual touching”?

Tags: canada, legal-terms, sexual-assault

Canadian case law and perhaps other jurisdictions’ make a big deal of “sexual touching” as a repeated term. How is this defined?

Answer (score 2):

> "sexual touching" means a person touching another person--
>
> (a) with any part of the body or with anything else, or
>
> (b) through anything, including anything worn by the person doing the touching or by the person being touched,
>
> in circumstances where a reasonable person would consider the touching to be sexual.

[s61HB](http://www5.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ca190082/s61hb.html) *Crimes Act* 1900 [new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

Comment: Potter Stewart would be proud.

Answer (score 2):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

To prove sexual assault, the Crown must prove that the touching was of a sexual nature.

For whether touching has a sexual nature see *R. v. Chase*, [[1987] 2 SCR 293, at para 11](https://canlii.ca/t/1ftlr#par11) (citations removed):

> The test to be applied in determining whether the impugned conduct has the requisite sexual nature is an objective one: "Viewed in the light of all the circumstances, is the sexual or carnal context of the assault visible to a reasonable observer." **The part of the body touched, the nature of the contact, the situation in which it occurred, the words and gestures accompanying the act, and all other circumstances surrounding the conduct, including threats which may or may not be accompanied by force, will be relevant.** The intent or purpose of the person committing the act, to the extent that this may appear from the evidence, may also be a factor in considering whether the conduct is sexual. If the motive of the accused is sexual gratification, to the extent that this may appear from the evidence, it may be a factor in determining whether the conduct is sexual. It must be emphasized, however, that the existence of such a motive is simply one of many factors to be considered, the importance of which will vary depending on the circumstances.

Touching need not be for sexual gratification in order to constitute sexual touching (*R. v. G.B.*, [2009 BCCA 88](https://canlii.ca/t/22mm1)). Touching intended to discipline or ridicule another can be sexual touching (*R. c. Bernier*, [1997 CanLII 9937](https://canlii.ca/t/1mx8t) (QCCA), aff'd [[1998] 1 S.C.R. 975](https://canlii.ca/t/1fqrx)).

As just one example that might not fit a colloquial understanding of "sexual assault": a judge has found that a skipping rope handle covered in latex glove, placed into someone's mouth and moved back and forth, *could* form the basis of sexual assault, depending on the rest of the circumstances (*R. v. Francis*, [2003 CanLII 2208](https://canlii.ca/t/1hlfm) (ON SC)).